# how to send link in emal using java mail sender

Tags: java, html-email

hi am trying to send link in email using gmail smtp.but it sending as String.can any body help me. thanks in advance.
java:

```
 String url="localhost:8080/#/activateuser/5575/958104f7-557e-4703-bcf7-55c9e37b7ad7";
        String content="<a href='"+url+"'>"+url+"</a>";
        msg.setContent(message1+" "+content,"text/html; charset=utf-8");

        // sends the e-mail
        Transport.send(msg);
        logger.info("Email sent succesfully");
```

response:
Verification Token : 5575 
To set password click on this url : localhost:8080/#/activateuser/5575/958104f7-557e-4703-bcf7-55c9e37b7ad7 (i want show this url as link)

Comment: you might need to add "http://" before "localhost:8080"

Comment: thank you very much @sumit badaya. its working fine

Answer (score 7, accepted):

you might need to add "http://" before "localhost:8080"